# Bias T to level shift output from oscillator

Tags: logic-gates, level-shifting, bias

I am using XOR gate HMC851LC3C to get an ultra-short pulse (200ps range). This logic gate requires inputs in the range of -2.5V to 0.5V. However, RF signals from my oscillator is sine wave -1V to 1V. I want to shift the range of this oscillator output to be -0.5 offset which means to -1.5V to 0.5V in order to satisfy the requirement of the logic gate. 
My question is, can I use a bias tee and apply sine waves on one side, -0.5V on the other side of the tee. Is this possible and will it change the jittering of the oscillator output after the tee?

Thank you
[datasheet of HMC851 logic gate](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/hmc851.pdf)

Comment: You say the logic gate " requires inputs in the range of -2.5V to 0.5V,"  but -2.5 V is below the absolute minimum input voltage range according to the datasheet you linked to.

Comment: I think I am confused what has been said in the datasheet. If you look at the Max Ratings on couple last pages, it said -2.5V to 0.5V

Comment: I'm looking at Absolute Maximum Ratings on page 4. It says input signals "-2 V to +0.5 V". These are the limits to avoid damaging the part.  On page 1 there are recommended operating conditions (how you should use the part for it to behave as advertised) giving input low voltage -1.0 to 0.0 V. If you make the low voltage below -2.0 you could damage the part. If you make the low voltage below -1.0 V, the behavior might not be what's specified in the datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution that's even simpler than what you proposed.

Notice that the inputs of this gate are differential. And the recommended logic low voltage includes 0 V.

That means if you bias one side of the differential input at 0 V, and apply a pure AC input (biased at 0 V) on the other side of the differential input, say 1 V peak-peak to avoid exceeding the maximum recommended high logic level (0.5 V), the gate should interpret this as a valid toggling logic input.

So you don't need a bias tee, just a dc-blocking capacitor (and a 3 dB attenuator) between your 2 V peak-peak oscillator and the HMC851 logic input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxVvI7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Would this affect the duty cycle of the output?

Comment: It looks really strange in the datasheet to see the input Vlow between -1 and 0 and Vhigh between -0.5 and 0.5. They overlap. How would the gate determine a signal at 0V?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, the input is differential so if AP>AN that would be a "1" and if AP<AN it will be a "0". Unfortunately it's not real clear what the minimum input amplitude is --- and the plot labelled "Amplitude vs input power" appears messed up, probably the labels for the different curves are switched around.

Comment: @crj11, if AN is at 0 V and AP gets a sine wave biased at 0 V, the output should have 50% d.c. Of course there will be some error.

Comment: @ThePhoton I wonder if the 0.5V max is just due to input diodes and the perhaps the common mode of the differential input does not extend that high.  The datasheet does not say anything about the common mode range.

Comment: @crj11, yes the 0.5 V max is due to input diodes (or at least to avoid forward biasing the b-c junction of the input BJT). But it's common for CML devices to be okay with inputs driven to that limit. Also notice there's a separate table for absolute maximum ratings.

Comment: If you want to keep the duty cycle close to 50%, low pass the signal on AP and feed that to AN.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis, since the inputs are terminated to ground, with ac-blocking as in my schematic, that should be the same as what I showed.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thank you for your solution. I actually already tried that. It works fine, I got around 1 ns pulse.  The reason I want to do the level shift is, from what I understand, if we attenuate amplitude of the sine wave, the rising time of the sine waves is slower, therefore, I cannot obtain very thin pulse. I assume that if we can keep the 2 Vpp, the gate will give a thinner pulse than 1 ns which is what we need for the experiment. Do you have any suggestion for this? Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to get a low duty cycle signal? Or a 50% d.c. square wave with 400 ps period?

Comment: The oscillator I am using produces 10 MHz sine waves. I do not think I want to change that output because I am afraid I might change the jittering. Therefore, I thought if I attenuate this signals, I will increase the output from the gate. 
And yes, I am trying to get a low duty cycle signal out from the gate, as low as possible.

Comment: Why are you using an XOR gate? Are you inputting the same sine wave (but phase shifted) to BP/BN as AP/AN? Why not just buffer your sine wave to get a square wave before the XOR?

Comment: Yes, I split the sine wave and send one to AP, delay the other and send to BP. 
I did not think of buffering the sine wave before the XOR. I am not sure what does that mean actually. Would you mind briefly explaining this technique.

Comment: I am basically trying to generate a ultrashort pulse, 100ps-400ps. I would be happy to get 400 ps but if I can go less by the buffering technique you mentioned that would be great. I only want to make sure any process after the oscillator will not change the jittering because we want the pulse jitter to be as stable as possible

Comment: Buffering means pass the signal through a digital buffer. The advantage would be to have faster edges at the input to the XOR gate. As a start, consider something like MC100EP16, although you might be able to find something faster.